# How to access ports in docker custom bridge networks

Tags: networking, nginx, docker, digital-ocean

The new `Docker` documentation says that you can still use `--link` in a default `bridge` network but that it's more secure to create your own `bridge network`. And then it says in custom `bridge` networks, you can no longer use `--link` to internally map a `port`.

So I would like to create a secure isolated, custom `bridge` network that can talk to eachother's ports.

For instance I have a `nginx` container in the `bridge` network but is also part of a `private network` which contains an `angular` application. How can I `proxy` calls from the `nginx` to a specified port (example `port 8080`) on the `angular container` without exposing the `angular` ports globally?

**UPDATE:**

I understand how to create containers in the same network and then use their container name to connect to each other with `ping`. What I don't understand is how to access another container's `port`. For instance if both `web2` and `nginx` are on the same network, I can `ping` `web2` from `nginx` great but if I run `curl web2:4200` from `nginx`, I get `Failed to connect to web2 port 4200: Connection refused`. How do I open up `port 4200` without exposing `port 4200` to the outside world?

`nginx` config file

```
upstream web {
    server web2:4200;
}

upstream api {
    server api:3000;
}



server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  url.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
```

web 2 network setting

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "f290157dd8f9b181bd544ee0b9814b1581adf61cee05c07e67a93df6bf85ecd3",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {},
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f290157dd8f9",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "application-network": {
                "EndpointID": "622f0afd4016eafc525b45c32c465c58b89ab543358ba860d31edac8ce877d83",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02"
            }
        }
    }
```

nginx network settings

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "94f2d21562f6af5334547110893470b3bece02a081620daec98446ecd7b3f14b",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "443/tcp": null,
        "80/tcp": null
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/94f2d21562f6",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "cfe8ec49e341aed2dd56bd61d1dff6867ddd0246c5a04ff8cebdeee571475bdb",
    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
    "Networks": {
        "application-network": {
            "EndpointID": "6242229877c5a29bfae1c0742d558daedf50fbe607b42722449367e5dda79371",
            "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03"
        },
        "bridge": {
            "EndpointID": "cfe8ec49e341aed2dd56bd61d1dff6867ddd0246c5a04ff8cebdeee571475bdb",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03"
        }
    }
}
```

I have moved this question over to here to isolate the question more: [docker container in same network cannot reach other container in same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845649/docker-container-in-same-network-cannot-reach-other-container-in-same-network)

Comment: you don't have to open up (publish) port 80, as long as the nginx container is listening on port 80 (e.g. `listen 0.0.0.0:80`), other containers in the network can connect to it. Are you using the official `nginx` image? Because this worked out of the box for me

Comment: @thaJeztah Would I run `docker run -it -H 0.0.0.0:80 nginx` for it to listen on that port? How can I get `nginx` to `listen` on port 80?

Comment: `-H` is only for the daemon, to specify what IP-address the API is reachable at. For the official nginx image, there's no configuration needed. This works; `docker network create a` `docker run -d --name=web2 --net=a nginx` `docker run --rm --net=a ubuntu sh -c "apt-get install -yq curl && curl web2"`

Comment: At this point, it is outside the scope of Docker configuration, and in the nginx configuration. Does nginx have a line such as `listen 80;` inside the `server` directive?

Comment: @AndyShinn ok I added the nginx config file

Comment: That seems fine. But what about the configuration of web2? It sounds like @thaJeztah is on the right path, the application on web2 is probably not listening on 0.0.0.0 and instead only listening on the container IP (so not outside connections can connect to it).

Comment: @AndyShinn I added the network configurations for web2 and nginx. Note I did not add `-p 4200:4200` when running the web2 container because I did not want to expose the port 4200 to outside the `application-network`. Was I wrong to do that?

Comment: No, I mean what is the command running inside web2 and the configuration of that application? This is no longer likely a Docker issue.

Comment: The `web2` is a `node` based image. Inside there is `http-server` returning a simple `index.html` file

Comment: @AndyShinn I wrote a comment above and the command is `http-server ./ -p 4200 -a 0.0.0.0 index.html`

Comment: @AndyShinn but inside the `nginx` container, `curl web2:4200` fails so I think there is a problem with the connection

Comment: Are you able to post the images and configurations used for each image so I can try to reproduce locally? This should work just fine without needing any ports exposed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100922/discussion-between-mlennie-and-andy-shinn).

Answer (score 3):

If both containers are connected to the same network, they can reach each other by *name*.

For example;

1. Create your own "bridge" network (bridge is the default)

   ```
   docker network create mybridge
   ```
2. Start a container on this network, and name it `containera`

   ```
   docker run -d --net=mybridge --name=containera nginx
   ```
3. Start another container on the same network, and try to "ping" containera

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --net=mybridge ubuntu

   root@1331cebaa93a:/# ping -w 4 containera
   PING containera (172.20.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from containera.mybridge (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
   64 bytes from containera.mybridge (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms
   64 bytes from containera.mybridge (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
   64 bytes from containera.mybridge (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms

   --- containera ping statistics ---
   4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3130ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.087/0.119/0.130/0.018 ms
   ```

Read more on docker networking here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

#### Container "aliases" in docker 1.10

Currently (docker 1.9.1), containers can only be reached using their "name" as host. However, docker 1.10 will support adding aliases for containers, either network-scoped, or container-scoped, using the same syntax as the current `--link`; `--link <container>:<alias>`.

For more information on the upcoming features for container-aliases here;
https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/work-with-networks.md#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks

Answer (score 2):

Links are not necessary as the containers in a custom network are discoverable via DNS (their entries are populated into the `/etc/hosts` file). Here is an example:

Create a new network:

```
docker network create test
```

Start a container in that network that just sits there doing nothing:

```
docker run -d --name sleeper --net test alpine sh -c "while true; do echo $(date); sleep 20; done"
```

Run another container with an interactive shell and check out the `hosts` file and connections to the `sleeper` container:

```
docker run -i -t --net test alpine sh
/ # cat /etc/hosts
172.18.0.4  cc90db123006
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.2  test3
172.18.0.2  test3.test
172.18.0.3  sleeper
172.18.0.3  sleeper.test
/ # ping sleeper
PING sleeper (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
^C
--- sleeper ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.103/0.105/0.107 ms
```

So, in this example, the `sleeper` container is similar to your `angular` container. Nginx would just proxy to `angular` and the port it was running on inside the container. No port mapping necessary.

The port you use would be the port that the `angular` application is listening on. So if that application is running nginx on port 80 then you would just connect to port 80.

Comment: oh, haha, looks like you beat me to it, I didn't refresh the page

Comment: oh, note that in docker 1.10, `/etc/hosts` will no longer be used for discovery, because discovery is now DNS based. See https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/841 and https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/767

Comment: maybe you were too slow waiting for those big ubuntu images to pull :p