# docker container in same network cannot reach other container in same network

Tags: ubuntu, curl, nginx, docker, digital-ocean

I'm using `ubuntu 15.10` on `digital ocean`

The following works
`docker network create a`

`docker run -d --name=nginx --net=a nginx`

`docker run -it --net=a --name web node bash`

`apt-get install -yq curl && curl nginx`

The opposite, trying to reach the `web container` from the `nginx container`, does not work for me.

I go into the web container:
`docker exec -it web bash`

Then I add my `index.html` file

Then I use `http-server` to serve an `index.html` file with the command `http-server ./ -p 4200 -a 0.0.0.0 index.html`.

`http-server` returns:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http:127.0.0.1:4200
  http:172.17.0.5:4200
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

If I then go into `nginx` and try `curl web:4200` then I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to web port 4200: Connection refused`

Comment: if you're using the above, you're overriding the web container's command, so there's no web server running, only curl

Comment: hey @thaJeztah ok I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spun up a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 droplet on DigitalOcean and
trying to reproduce this;

Using the quick n dirty `curl | sh` install method - not best practice, but heck, it's easy:

```
apt-get install -y curl && curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Create network `mynetwork` and containers `weba` and `webb` on that network;

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run --net mynetwork --name weba -d node sh -c 'npm install http-server -g && mkdir -p /public && echo "welcome to weba" > /public/index.html && http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4200'
docker run --net mynetwork --name webb -d node sh -c 'npm install http-server -g && mkdir -p /public && echo "welcome to webb" > /public/index.html && http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4200'
```

Reach webb from inside weba

```
docker exec -it weba sh -c 'curl http://webb:4200'
# welcome to webb
```

Reach weba from inside webb

```
docker exec -it webb sh -c 'curl http://weba:4200'
# welcome to weba
```

That looks to work for me; is there anything different on your environment?

Comment: Yes that completely works. Is that method that you used to install `docker` a safe and secure method of installing it? Would you recommend I still go back and try and install by following the `docker install` docs or is that method fine? thank you

Comment: The method is fine, just that not everybody likes piping curl directly to the shell (which is reasonable), also the script tries to detect the platform it's installing on (which is a "best effort attempt"), which "works", but, for example on CentOS/RHEL systems, devicemapper is used as a driver, and the default (automatic) configuration is not really suitable for production setup

Comment: All hail thaJeztah!!

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help. Most things in docker aren't *super* complicated, but there's a lot of things to know and it takes a while to know them. Baby steps, rinse and repeat, a lot of failing and learning is part of that learning process. Don't be afraid to try things (and it's not embarrassing to fail, we all did at times!) Happy testing!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to question whether you network isolation is an important part of why you are using containers.

Consider avoiding the issue by running your containers on the same network as the Host OS.

On modern Linux systems running `systemd`, you have access to the  `systemd-nspawn`  container solution, without installing any additional software. It provides process isolation, resource management, chroot'ed environments, and the ability to share the Host OS network with the [--network-veth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn#use_host_networking) option.